# Need to change variable name in a for loop everytime in Java Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, date, variables

I am a beginner level programmer and I am again here to take everybody's help and solve my problem. Actually I don't have an error this time but I need to do something which I am not able to,
The thing is that I want to use a for loop 3 times and everytime I have a condition to check if my Quantity1 = 0 or not, again if my Quantity2 is = 0 or not and same for the third time. I can also repeat the code 3 times but I need to do this is because, I am uploading my data to a realtime database. And I am uploading my SelectedDate1 if Quantity1 != 0 and same for the three times, but to read them I have to know that how many Quantities and SelectedDates are uploaded and for that I have created a variable OrderQuantity. But the problem is if the user has selected the 1st date and the 3rd date and not the 2nd one as its quantity is 0, so when it is uploaded it shows `OrderQuantity=2`and the selectedDate1 comes under 1 but the 3rd date comes under 2nd node with name 3, but it should come with the name of variable+i, I hope you understand my question. And if not, please comment and I'll provide you an english video for what I want. Hoping your help as soon as possible.-

I think there is no use of main_activity.xml as it will make my question very big.

But here goes my MainActivity.java (without imports as it was very big)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerFragment.applyDate, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    String CurrentDateString;
    TextView mainDate;
    Integer OrderQuantity = 3;
    String itemOneDate;
    String itemTwoDate;
    String itemThreeDate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button SelectDate1 = findViewById(R.id.SelectDateButton1);
        Button SelectDate2 = findViewById(R.id.SelectDateButton2);
        Button SelectDate3 = findViewById(R.id.SelectDateButton3);

        SelectDate1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DatePickerFragment datePicker = DatePickerFragment.newInstance(1, MainActivity.this);
                datePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Pick item order date");

                mainDate = SelectDate1;
            }
        });

        SelectDate2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DatePickerFragment datePicker = DatePickerFragment.newInstance(2, MainActivity.this);
                datePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Pick item order date");

                mainDate = SelectDate2;
            }
        });

        SelectDate3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DatePickerFragment datePicker = DatePickerFragment.newInstance(3, MainActivity.this);
                datePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Pick item order date");

                mainDate = SelectDate3;
            }
        });

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> FoodAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.FoodList, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        FoodAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        Spinner SelectItem1 = findViewById(R.id.SelectItem1);
        SelectItem1.setAdapter(FoodAdapter);
        SelectItem1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        Spinner SelectItem2 = findViewById(R.id.SelectItem2);
        SelectItem2.setAdapter(FoodAdapter);
        SelectItem2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        Spinner SelectItem3 = findViewById(R.id.SelectItem3);
        SelectItem3.setAdapter(FoodAdapter);
        SelectItem3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> QuantityAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Quantity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        QuantityAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        Spinner Quantity1 = findViewById(R.id.SelectQuantity1);
        Quantity1.setAdapter(QuantityAdapter);
        Quantity1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        Spinner Quantity2 = findViewById(R.id.SelectQuantity2);
        Quantity2.setAdapter(QuantityAdapter);
        Quantity2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        Spinner Quantity3 = findViewById(R.id.SelectQuantity3);
        Quantity3.setAdapter(QuantityAdapter);
        Quantity3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        Button DoneButton = findViewById(R.id.DoneButton);

        EditText PersonName = findViewById(R.id.PersonName);
        EditText PersonPhone = findViewById(R.id.PersonPhone);
        EditText PersonAddress = findViewById(R.id.PersonAddress);

        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        DoneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                DatabaseReference Name = database.getReference(PersonPhone.getText().toString() + "/Name");
                Name.setValue(PersonName.getText().toString());

                DatabaseReference Phone = database.getReference(PersonPhone.getText().toString() + "/Phone");
                Phone.setValue(PersonPhone.getText().toString());

                DatabaseReference Address = database.getReference(PersonPhone.getText().toString() + "/Address");
                Address.setValue(PersonAddress.getText().toString());    

//I need help here in these three if-else statements

                if (Quantity1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("0")) {
                    OrderQuantity -= 1;
                } else {
                    DatabaseReference dateOne = database.getReference(PersonPhone.getText().toString() + "/Orders" + "/1" + "/Date");
                    dateOne.setValue(itemOneDate);
                }

                if (Quantity2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("0")) {
                    OrderQuantity -= 1;
                } else {
                    DatabaseReference dateOne = database.getReference(PersonPhone.getText().toString() + "/Orders" + "/2" + "/Date");
                    dateOne.setValue(itemTwoDate);
                }

                if (Quantity3.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("0")) {
                    OrderQuantity -= 1;
                } else {
                    DatabaseReference dateOne = database.getReference(PersonPhone.getText().toString() + "/Orders" + "/3" + "/Date");
                    dateOne.setValue(itemOneDate);
                }

                DatabaseReference OrderQuantities = database.getReference(PersonPhone.getText().toString() + "/OrderQuantity");
                OrderQuantities.setValue(OrderQuantity);

            }
        });
    }

    public void setDate(int selectedYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDay, int buttonNumber) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, selectedYear);
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, selectedMonth);
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, selectedDay);

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        String CurrentDateString = format.format(c.getTime());
        mainDate.setText(CurrentDateString);

        if (buttonNumber == 1) {
            itemOneDate = CurrentDateString;
        } else if (buttonNumber == 2) {
            itemTwoDate = CurrentDateString;
        } else if (buttonNumber == 3) {
            itemThreeDate = CurrentDateString;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
}
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClBW7.jpg) is the image of the data saved on realtime database when 1st and 3rd date are selected.-

Also see that [what](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1WhO.jpg) I have selected on the virtual device.

And [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=33BFCdL0Di0) is the link from where I learnt to make a datePickerFragment for selecting date.

Comment: what exactly you need help with? this is way too much code and a little too confusing. so your main problem is "why aren't an entry in DB with `2` in the `orders` key? am I correct?

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. See if you either can use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project, in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: I need for loop in which quanitity+i means quantity1, then second time quantity2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Edit: go object-oriented

Edit: since my first two suggestions didn’t work for you, I am suggesting using some abstraction. Declare a class to hold a spinner and its related data, and iterate a list of such objects. Your list can hold a variable number of objects so there will be a variable number of spinners. Caveat: I don’t know Android UI programming, so may be missing a detail or two there. And I still have not compiled my code myself.

```
public class MySpinner {
    private FirebaseDatabase database;
    private Spinner quantity;
    private String number;
    private String itemDate;

    public MySpinner(FirebaseDatabase database,
            Spinner quantity, String number, String itemDate) {
        this.database = database;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.number = number;
        this.itemDate = itemDate;
    }

    /* @return true if there was a positive quantity to process, false otherwise */
    public boolean processQuantity() {
        if (quantity.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("0")) {
            return false;
        }

        DatabaseReference dateOne = database.getReference(PersonPhone.getText().toString()
                 + "/Orders" + number + "/Date");
        dateOne.setValue(itemDate);

        return true;
    }
}
```

I have also object-orientedly fitted the class with a method to do the work for each spinner. Now with a list of objects of your class you may process each in turn in a loop like this:

```
    for (MySpinner mySpinner : yourListOfMySpinners) {
        if (! mySpinner.processQuantity()) { // quantity was 0
            OrderQuantity -= 1;
        }
    }
```

I am leaving to yourself to fill objects into your list. There will probably also be some adjusting and tailoring that you will want to do.

Original answer follows.

### Use an array or list

It’s not uncommon for beginners in programming to ask that question. It’s not quite the right question to ask. What you need is to iterate over your quantities in a loop. The solution to that is to put them into an array or list and iterate over that array or list. Code is not tested.

```
    Spinner[] quantities = { Quantity1, Quantity2, Quantity3 };
    for (int i = 0; i < quantities.length; i++) {
        if (quantities[i].getSelectedItem().toString().equals("0")) {
            OrderQuantity -= 1;
        } else {
            DatabaseReference dateOne = database.getReference(PersonPhone.getText().toString() + "/Orders/" + (i + 1) + "/Date");
            dateOne.setValue(itemTwoDate);
        }
    }
```

While it would be possible to select a variable the way you describe, it’s neither the best, the easiest nor the nicest solution.

### Or use a method

An alternative is to declare a method that does the job for each quantity and call it three times without using any loop. In your case the method may need to take quite many arguments, though, which is not ideal.

```
    processSpinner(database, Quantity1, "/1", itemOneDate);
    processSpinner(database, Quantity2, "/2", itemTwoDate);
    processSpinner(database, Quantity3, "/3", itemThreeDate);
```

Your method may be declared like:

```
private void processSpinner(FirebaseDatabase database,
            Spinner quantity, String number, String itemDate) {
    if (quantity.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("0")) {
        OrderQuantity -= 1;
    } else {
        DatabaseReference dateOne = database.getReference(PersonPhone.getText().toString()
                 + "/Orders" + number + "/Date");
        dateOne.setValue(itemDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: The array method u told I tried was not working for me :( and the method way was not giving me expeceted output because What I want is - 
What is given  = I have an Integer which is equal to the number of times the loop needs to be executed, and the string is `TotalOrders`.

Expected Answer = I need the the loop runs TotalOrders.length number of times and everytime it should upload `AllValuesArrayOrList[i]` and upload to path i.

Comment: I have added a suggestion not quite what you said, but along similar ideas, so I hope you can take some inspiration from there. It’s at the start of the answer.